# Attach inputFilter to dynamcially created field elements

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2, validation

Until now I have been binding input filters to the form in the module, in other words I have been creating elements in the form, adding input filters to the elements on the module side.

For example check this [example](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/)

Right now im creating text field elements dynamically depending upon the requirements, like this in my form

```
//Form
public function addNamesTextFieldElement($names)
    {
        foreach($names as $name)
        {
            $nameTextField = new Element\Text($name->getName());
            $nameTextField->setAttribute('type', "text");
            $nameTextField->setLabel($name->getName());

            $this->add($nameTextField );
        }
    }
```

What would be best approach where to add/attach input filters to such dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use this approach, but something like this would work, providing you have already assigned an InputFilter to the form:

```
public function addNamesTextFieldElement($names)
{
    $factory     = new InputFactory();
    foreach($names as $name)
    {
        $nameTextField = new Element\Text($name->getName());
        $nameTextField->setAttribute('type', "text");
        $nameTextField->setLabel($name->getName());

        $this->add($nameTextField );

        $this->getInputFilter()->add(
            $factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => $name->getName(),
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 1,
                            'max'      => 100,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ))
        );
    }
}
```